# Using InstanceType<T> with factory function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a fairly simple factory function that uses a map of constructors to determine the right type of object to create based on a string parameter passed in.

I am aware of the factory pattern described in the examples that passes the class constructor to the factory, but in my case I need to pass in a simple string.

```
class Vehicle {
    public wheels: number;
}
class Car extends Vehicle {
    public drive: number
}
class Bike extends Vehicle {
    public ride: number;
}

const CTORS = {
    car: Car,
    bike: Bike
}

type VehicleTypes = typeof CTORS;

function factory<T extends keyof VehicleTypes>(name: T): InstanceType<VehicleTypes[T]> {
    let ctor: VehicleTypes[T] = CTORS[name];

    // un-comment to see error    
    // return new ctor();

    return new ctor() as InstanceType<VehicleTypes[T]>;
}

let abc = factory('bike');
abc.ride = 5;   // type checks ok
```

The above works and type checks ok, but the explicit typing on the return is necessary to avoid a compiler error:

```
(Type 'Car | Bike' is not assignable to type 'InstanceType<{ car: typeof Car; bike: typeof Bike; }[T]>'.  Type 'Car' is not assignable to type 'InstanceType<{ car: typeof Car; bike: typeof Bike; }[T])
```

I suspect typescript is complaining that the return value isn't a union of all potential instances. But I can't work out how to apply the types such that the explicit typing override isn't necessary. I have also tried the below which doesn't help either:

```
type ReturnTypes = { 
    [P in keyof VehicleTypes]: InstanceType<VehicleTypes[P]>
}
function factory<T extends keyof VehicleTypes>(name: T): ReturnTypes[T] {
    let ctor = CTORS[name];
    return new ctor();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is currently a limitation of TypeScript: unresolved conditional types, meaning those which depend on a yet-to-be-specified generic type parameter, are opaque to the compiler; it can't really see that some value is assignable to it.  The type `InstanceType<T>` is [defined](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.6.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1494) like this:

```
type InstanceType<T extends new (...args: any) => any> = 
  T extends new (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any;
```

That's a conditional type, and *inside* the implementation of `factory()`, the type `InstanceType<VehicleTypes[T]>` is unresolved, since `T` is not specified.

---

There are several open GitHub issues with suggestions for making such unresolved conditional types easier to deal with, but none of them are currently implemented (as of TS3.7).  Here are some links to them if you care enough to go there and give them a  or otherwise advocate for them:

- [microsoft/TypeScript#13995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995): generic typed values should be narrowed inside function implementations
- [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085): generic type parameters should be narrowed inside function implmentations
- [microsoft/TypeScript#23132](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23132): allow constrained generics to resolve conditional types earlier
- [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808): allow generic type parameters constrained to unit types so that control flow analysis can narrow generic type parameters
- [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912): control flow analysis should be used to produce conditional return types

---

For now, I'd say either use a type assertion as you did, *or* find a way to represent your type in a way that doesn't rely on conditional types.  One possible way forward here is to note that class constructors in TypeScript are given a `prototype` property of the same type as their instance type.  This is a bit strange and not really correct, since the actual prototype won't have any of the instance-only properties, but [that's the way it is and it's unlikely to change](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11558).

So, you can make your own `InstanceType` that uses this fact:

```
type MyInstanceType<T extends { prototype: any }> = T['prototype'];
```

And then you can write

```
function factory<T extends keyof VehicleTypes>(name: T): MyInstanceType<VehicleTypes[T]> {
    let ctor: VehicleTypes[T] = CTORS[name];
    return new ctor();
}
```

with no error, and you still get the type checking you expect:

```
let abc = factory('bike');
abc.ride = 5;   // type checks ok
```

---

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBqCmALAlqe0DeAoavoAcBXAIxFWgHdF54QIAuaAO0IFtj4AnaAXmgBYA3FgC+WUJBgBhMN3gAPAC7wmAExgIUaTDjxFS5VZ2QA3eIxbsuvaAEYATMLESo0AELIA1ugXK1GpFQQdGw8AhIyYGhjVXNmNg5uPlsnLHEAeyYIRWgpABUAeQAlAGUbULxgWUYZTgAaXVxiLziPb1E0xQBPfHRNIPg8nvgYPm7e9IAzXMLS4Sxx9ABZLoBJLMUwJmBB4YAePOhfFXVMAk50xUvhxi2u6BEAPhs8gG0AcnwLq8X3gF15pNCNtFMhMtBJmBgFdOF0DkclCcYN4ulM4IE0ENehBHgAKJhgVhxPIASkYK3W2S2Oyx8D2-Uxwwgrzyf2eFVwwRy0PSnEYDOCtOZrJs+WKJVeBKJAMa0XgikInCYzHgFGgPM4uJJqSwXOgYGIUT4kI1XVx72a3ne2qwBuAADoYug+ABWQR4AD0Hugi3V1GAnhg6U8QA)

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question perfectly. I had started to uncover some of those links you mentioned and was reaching a similar conclusion. Thanks for the prototype trick. I am happy to just use assertions, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something wrong.